# uploaded files are null

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, file-io

I'm trying to upload a image via a form to crop it in another php file, but when I upload the file it doesn't seem to upload.

Here's the form:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="cropNsend.php" method="POST" ENCTYPE=”multipart/form-data”>
            <input type="text" id="inputName" name="inputName" value="NAME"><br>
            <input type="text" id="inputTel" name="inputTel" value="TELEFON"><br>
            <input type="text" id="inputmail" name="inputmail" value="EMAIL"><br>
            <input type="text" id="inputAdr" name="inputAdr" value="ADRESSE"><br>
            <input type="file" id="inputPic" name="inputPic"><br>
            <input id="x" type="hidden" name="x" value="130">
            <input id="y" type="hidden" name="y" value="83">
            <input id="w" type="hidden" name="w" value="155">
            <input id="h" type="hidden" name="h" value="155">
</form>
```

I submit the form woth javasript vai $("#uploadForm").submit();

Everything seems to upload fine, but the file.

Here's the php code:

```
session_start();

define("FILEREPOSITORY", "./");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{    
   if(isset($_POST["inputName"]) && isset($_POST["inputmail"]) &&
    isset($_POST["inputAdr"]) && isset($_POST["inputTel"]))
  {   
    $_SESSION["x"] = $_POST["x"];
    $_SESSION["y"] = $_POST["y"];
    $_SESSION["width"] = $_POST["w"];
    $_SESSION["height"] = $_POST["h"];
    $_SESSION["inputName"] = $_POST["inputName"];
    $_SESSION["inputmail"] = $_POST["inputmail"];
    $_SESSION["inputTel"] = $_POST["inputTel"];
    $_SESSION["inputAdr"] = $_POST["inputAdr"];

    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo $_FILES["inputPic"]["name"];
    echo $_FILES["inputPic"]["type"];
    echo $_FILES["inputPic"]["size"];   
}
```

var_dump($_FILES) is an array(0).

hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes are wrong for ENCTYPE

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="" method="POST" ENCTYPE=”multipart/form-data”>
```

try this:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ENCTYPE=”multipart/form-data”  with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Please do copy past whole new tag with value

Comment: your multipart/form-data wrapped with ” instead of "

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to put this as a comment, but I'm new so low rep.

Try checking if file uploads are enabled in your apache2/nginx/server config files or perhaps even your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Check php.ini and set larger limits, like

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Check nginx config

```
client_max_body_size 100m;
```

And don't forget to restart services..

Other possible problems might occur because of

1. too many post variables
2. missing enctype
3. form inside of another form
4. another input with same name
5. inaccessible/not writable temp folder for web server